# Group Theory Homomorphism

Tags: group-theory

is there group homomorphism surjective between any group and it's subgroup ?
i.e. if G is a group and H is a subgroup of G , is there f:G -> H such that f is group homomorphism surjective ?

Comment: Did you try to answer this question? You should have come to an answer pretty fast if you tried - there is no onto map $S_3\to C_3$, and these are two of the smallest groups out there.

Answer (score 2):

No.  By the first isomorphism theorem, given a surjective homomorphism $\varphi:G\rightarrow H$, we have that $G/\operatorname{ker}(\varphi)\cong H$.  The kernel must be normal, and not all groups have normal subgroups of the order required.  In particular, an easy example is any noncyclic simple group $G$ and any nontrivial proper subgroup $H$.